# Android FTP upload error: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, ftp

I got this ftp upload method:

```
try {
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

    // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
    ftp.connect("ftp.atw.hu", 21, "username", "password");

    // Set binary mode.
    ftp.bin();

    // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
    ftp.cwd("web");

    // Upload some files.
    ftp.stor(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Documents/Festivale.db"));
    //ftp.stor(new File("comicbot-latest.png"));

    // You can also upload from an InputStream, e.g.
    // ftp.stor(new FileInputStream(new File("test.png")), "test.png");
    // ftp.stor(someSocket.getInputStream(), "blah.dat");

    // Quit from the FTP server.
    ftp.disconnect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Jibble.
}
```

I got force close with the following log:

```
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.example.festivale_v2.main$8.onClick(main.java:106)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-27 14:26:09.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong? I've tried it on my phone resulting in the same error. It has internet permission.

Comment: check your libs folder containing particular .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleFTP class obviously cannot be found.

You should check your classpath (project properties > Java build path):

- In the Libraries tab: add the corresponding jar
- In Order and Export: check the jar so that it's exported

Comment: added that jar... in the begining

Comment: Did you make sure it's exported?

Comment: what is that mean? how to do it?

Comment: In "Order and Export" tab, just check the checkbox next to your jar